# Manually Create DataTable Class?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

Let describe My situation:

I want to create simple **Data-Modifier**, which have only `DataGrid` on page and that grid can bind to any table (Choose by User) in `DataBase` which Specified via application Connection-String. at the end User can save this grid (as forms) with `Table binding`.

I create this **Data-Modifier in Wpf** for User who in charge to Create Forms, and decide to use **Silverlight as Preview and Execute** these Form by User.

> In Order to create these project's, I test **Data-table**, and find it perfect for my usage.It can **load any Struct** with just simple Select-Command (Loud and Clear). Also Data-Table can told me which row has change (inserted, updated and deleted). even get each row as DataRow(it's awsome).

But there is one big Problem here: **SilverLight does not support system.data**. I really Confused.

> Q: How Create manually DataTable-Class with Blow Condition's

1. That class must have property like 2d array which return data.
2. That class (or inside Property) can fill data grid property.
3. Data-Grid-Row's  can delete, insert or update and so that class must have an ability to work with grid.
4. That Class can get list of changed row's with state.

Comment: I don't know the answer offhand however I'll mention a few things that come to mind here. I'll mention the obvious and what you see to have found, that Silverlight only uses a subset of the .NET Framework used by WPF.  

Are you using asynchronous WCF RIA calls? I believe it is a requirement so that Silverlight doesn't become locked if there are network problems.

Comment: Thanks GisplacedGuy, I keep that in my mind